# How to check DST or Daylight Saving time is on or off in android application

Tags: android

Can anybody tell how to check DST or Day Light Saving Time  is on or off in android application

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the current DST offset. If the result is not 0, DST is active.

```
int dstOffset = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
```