# How to find the begin date and enddate for daylight saving timing using date in year in android

Tags: java, android

How to find the begin date and end date for day light saving time using date in year in android eg If 09.03.2014 is day light saving time begin date and is day light saving time end date 02.11.2014  need to find end date.In my application am using East Time Zone GMT-5

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't depend only on Date and Time. It also depends on the Time Zone you are in.

Comment: I answered this same question for you a few days ago :-)

Comment: Do you need to know if today's date need a daylight offset or do you need to know for any date?

Comment: @natronite I want to check for any date

Comment: That's what I figured. Check my answer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140408/how-to-check-dst-or-daylight-saving-time-is-on-or-off-in-android-application.

Comment: @natronite I want to find DST start and end date  of all year

Comment: @natronite example start date 09.03.2014  enddate 02-11-2014

Comment: @mohan please update your question with exactly what you need, your comments are all asking for different things to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `TimeZone` you can retrieve it with `inDaylightTime(Date)`.

To get the `TimeZone` you need:

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00");
```

More here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: Subject to exactly which timezone @mohan wants, it should be "US/Eastern", "America/New_York" or one of various others. GMT-05:00 is a fixed offset so is never in DST.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the current DST offset. If the result is not 0, DST is active.

```
int dstOffset = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
```

Comment: @DaveMorrisey I want to check for date Est Time Zone GMT-5

Comment: You should add more detail to the question, you haven't mentioned this.